# Is it required to have primary keys from both tables in lookup table as well?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using **MySQL 5.7 with WB6.3** for my study project to design the **ER diagram.**

When I try to create **many-to-many** relationship. By default MySQL will mark the primary keys of both tables as primary key in the lookup table as well.

**Is it really need to have primary keys from both table as primary key in the lookup table as well ?**

Please see the table `car_item` in my diagram below I've removed primary key from both red`(idcar,iditem)`. Please tell me if PK is needed for them

[image: My ER diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a **unique key** for `(car_idcar, item_list_iditem_list)`, but it doesn't necessarily have to be the **primary key**. This way, you ensure that you don't create duplicate relationships between the same rows in the two tables.

A table can only have one primary key, and the `car_item` table already has primary key `id_car_item`, so the foreign keys for the relation can't also be a primary key. But there can be an arbitrary number of unique keys.

Some purists might say that if there are two unique keys (a primary key is also a unique key), one of them is redundant. In your case, the `id_car_item` column may not really be necessary, as it's not common to refer to relations in other tables, the relation table is just used to join the other two tables. But this isn't always the case. For instance, a user table might have a unique `username` column (since you don't allow multiple users to have the same name), but also a `userid` primary key that's used as the foreign key in other tables (this allows renaming users without having to update all the foreign keys). Some database designers like to have an auto-increment column in every table, as it's useful as a reference in user interface applications.

Comment: I like what you have explained, but after I've mark both columns as unique key, I can not link `a car to multiple items` and `multiple car to an item`. Do you have any solution on this ?

Comment: Didn't I answer this in your new question? You don't understand multi-column keys, go back to your textbook and look it up.

Answer (score 0):

It is common practice to have a composite primary key in a table that implements many-to-many. This key should consist of primary keys from both tables on each side of the many-to-many relationship.

Such approach guarantees data consistency and eliminates duplication.

In your case you should define a composite primary key for table `car_item` that would consist of two fields `{ car_idcar, item_list_iditem_list }`
The column `id_car_item` is not needed and can be dropped, it was probably added automatically, as many RDBMS add surrogate PK by default.

Comment: I just curious in case that we mark `car_idcar, item_list_iditem_list` as PK,  PK is unique for the table. So how I can put the same `item`(e.g. item id=001) to match with other `car`(e.g. idcar=100 and 101 and 102) ?

Comment: Yes, PK is unique, but in our case PK is a pair of two values, so each pair has to be unique, not individual numbers inside that pair
That means you can have the following combinations (item,car) : (001,100), (001,101), (001,102). What you cannot have is the PAIR (001,100) twice - but you don't really need to ;-)

Comment: this really help me learn about using multiple columns as table key.

Comment: That's great! Learning is always a good thing.
Please upvote my answer if it helped you :-)